# What happens when a Scala "Future" is garbage collected?

Tags: scala, garbage-collection, future

Say I have a `Stream` that's rather expensive to compute. I can easily create a thread that "computes ahead" just by writing something like

```
import scala.actors.Futures._
val s = future { stream.size }
```

If I then throw away the reference to this `Future`, will that thread be killed off by the garbage collector?

Comment: No. The garbage collector never kills threads. The computation might have side effects which the garbage collector can't know about, in other words, the thread might be doing something important which the garbage collector can't know - so it can never safely stop the thread.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. The thread belongs to the scheduler. In any case, the scheduler has a reference to the body un-finished Future (this happens in `a.start()`), so it won't be garbage collected before completion.

```
object Futures {

  /** Arranges for the asynchronous execution of `body`,
   *  returning a future representing the result.
   *
   *  @param  body the computation to be carried out asynchronously
   *  @return      the future representing the result of the
   *               computation
   */
  def future[T](body: => T): Future[T] = {
    val c = new Channel[T](Actor.self(DaemonScheduler))
    val a = new FutureActor[T](_.set(body), c)
    a.start()
    a
  }
}
```